# Name for stories which do not contain names of the characters

Tags: terminology

Perhaps this is against the canons of literary construction but, is there a name for the style of tales, novels, and books which do not contain names for any of the characters?

I can only think of Monterroso's microstory *The dinosaur*:

> Cuando despertó, el dinosaurio todavía estaba allí.

But I wonder if there are longer literary works with such construction. I would also be interested if this way of constructing characters has a known school or if it's an isolated way of writing and appears only from time to time. (For school I mean e.g. the stream of consciousness which was used by Faulkner, Joyce, among others.)

Comment: I expect there are many in the science fiction genre: *Last and First Men* by Olaf Stapledon is one that immediately comes to mind.

Comment: As it stands, this seems a bit like a request for lists/recommendations, which is off-topic here. I suggest two possible ways you could edit to make it clearly on-topic: (1) if you remember a **particular story like this which you'd like to identify**, make this a [tag:story-identification] question; (2) if you're interested in this genre/style of writing in general, then **ask about the *name* of this type of story** and tag it [tag:terminology] (a good answer would either give examples or point you to a resource that does).

Comment: *Eden* by Stanisław Lem is another.

Comment: It is not for book recommendation. Thanks for the terminology tag, I didn't know where to properly set my question. See the added edits.

Comment: @user2820579 your main question seems to be asking for a list of works. That is off-topic here. I'd suggest removing that part ("I wonder if there are longer literary works with such construction").

Comment: @muru I've tried to edit this to be more on-topic. Hopefully that's OK by the original poster.

Comment: Asking if there's a name for this approach/construction is certainly on-topic, even if the likely answer might be "there's no specific name for it, because it's so rarely used". In any case, to avoid your post being closed, I'd [edit] it to remove the sentence "But I wonder..." and change "I can only think of" to "An example is", as the existing wording encourages users to post further examples, which is definitely *off-topic*. And I can't resist adding an obvious one: *[The Unnameable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unnamable_(novel))* by Samual Beckett.

Comment: Thank you for your editings and the suggestion.